# "Также" или "так же" — как в данном случае правильно?

Tags: орфография

Для друзей я всё также оставался надёжным товарищем.

Как здесь правильно написать слово также?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно: **Для друзей я всё так же оставался надёжным товарищем.**

Местоимение ТАК + частица ЖЕ в значении "так же, как и раньше".

При слитном написании присоединительного союза ТАКЖЕ его можно заменить союзом-синонимом ТОЖЕ, но здесь это невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **Для друзей я всё так же оставался надёжным товарищем.**.

Вот трудный случай. Нужно различать:

- Он владеет французским, **также как** и немецким. (*Также как* в значении союза: он владеет французским и немецким.)
- Он владеет французским **так же, как** и немецким. (Он владеет французским так же хорошо, как владеет немецким.)