# Можно ли нерасчлененный союз «так же как и» писать слитно ("также как и")?

Tags: орфография, союзы, слитно-раздельно

Многие пользователи пишут именно так,  примеры слитного написания встречаются и в литературе:

*Масло, **также как и** вода,  является источником живой информации* (2003).

*Он бы мог решить, **также как и** любой другой зритель, что художник неравнодушен к модели*  (2015).

В этих примерах  союз «также» по значению равен союзу «тоже: *Масло **тоже**  является источником живой информации, **как и** вода.*

Однако в словаре рекомендуется только **раздельное написание**, что подтверждает и Грамота.ру.  Конфликт практической орфографии и правил?

Мне такая форма (так же как и) кажется нелогичной и некрасивой. А что думаете вы и какая форма письма вам чаще встречается?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1. Вопросы, в которых пользователи пишут союз «также как и»
   [http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=также%20как%20и](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B8)
2. Из толкового словаря  Кузнецова

**ТАКЖЕ**, союз. Присоединяет однородные члены предложения или предложения в составе сложного. Он был хорошим другом, учился т. хорошо. Брат бросил курить, вам т. следует сделать это. Он согласен, мы т. не возражаем. Ты устал, я т. <**Также как**, в зн. союза. Он владеет французским, **также как и** немецким.

3. **Вопрос № 225522**   Меня интересует сочетание "также как и". В искусстве не существует такого понятия, как "достаточность", также как и в любви (вопрос 223012). В №№ 222025, 214273 в сочетании "так же как" авторы вопросов пишут "также" слитно. Вопрос: существует ли союз "также как и", который по значению соответствовал бы союзу "равно как и" или же такое сочетание, имея сравнительное значение, должно всегда писаться раздельно, как Вы и предлагаете в ответах №181162, №187882, №199996. Спасибо!

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. О значении союза *так же как и* Вы можете прочесть в электронных словарях (окно «Проверка слова»).

4. **Вопрос № 298109**   Здравствуйте! В толковом словаре под ред. Кузнецова есть такой пример в статье "Также": "Он владеет французским, также как и немецким". Разве не раздельно должно писаться в этом случае "так же"? В ответах в Справке в аналогичных случаях рекомендуется писать именно раздельно. Спасибо!

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. **Орфографическая** рекомендация – писать союзное сочетание так же как (и) раздельно.

Comment: Если можно, то тогда на "тоже" можно заменить, но что-то оно туда не подставляется. Или запятую поставить перед "как".

Comment: *Конфликт практической орфографии и правил?* — вам же вашими словами: *Это неправильная практика, не берите с нее пример. Здесь грамматику надо знать.*

Comment: Любите вы все подставлять и переставлять. Я же говорю — в значении союза "тоже"!  А в грамматике будет рассматриваться  единый составной союз ТАКЖЕ КАК И, отнесенный к обособленному обороту, не надо его делить на части. Конечно, против официальной орфографии не пойдешь, но надо с пониманием относиться к тем, кто пишет союз слитно, и камешки в них не бросать.

Comment: Там нет значения "тоже"! Оно туда не подставляется. Вы его подставляете так: *Масло тоже, как и вода, является источником живой информации.* В обособленный оборот оно у вас не входит. Причин для понимания не вижу. Оно пишется раздельно, потому что "же" можно изъять — так и проверяется, в каком смысле оно используется.

Comment: oleedd, вы содержание не отличаете от формы, вот в чем проблема. У союзов ТОЖЕ, ТАКЖЕ  значение "в равной степени, одинаково",а при раздельном написании у нас будет сравнительное значение. Вот от этого значения мы и уходим, используя слитное написание. Кстати, у Кузнецова  ТАКЖЕ КАК И пишется слитно, как и союз ТАКЖЕ КАК. Еще неизвестно, откуда взялось это раздельное письмо. Орфографическая рекомендация! А грамматическая рекомендация где?

Comment: В этих примерах как раз и нужно сравнение. *Также как и = тоже как и.* Разве нет? Лучше обратитесь к этому своему ответу: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439793

Comment: Обратилась... Подстановка – это формальное доказательство, там важна частица ВСЁ,  – к союзу ТАКЖЕ ее не приклеишь. А вот у М.Г. правильная мысль. Когда у нас значение в такой же степени (так же хорошо), то нужно раздельное письмо. Жаль, что он ушел, у него хорошее чувство языка.

Comment: Вы предлагаете заменить союз "так же как (и)" на "также как и"? С Грамоты: *! Не смешивать с сочетанием местоименного определителя «так» с частицей «же» и союза «как (и)».* Мы обсуждаем лишь союз.

Comment: Мне нужен цельный союз ТАКЖЕ КАК (И). Он был у Кузнецова, его значение – приравнивание ситуаций, а не их сравнение.  А Грамота (Лопатин, скорее всего) его отменила по орфографическим соображениям, по форме. А изменения значений они не видят.

Comment: Ну тогда разницы между ними нет и нужно выбрать что-то одно. Верно? Мы говорим лишь о том, когда запятая **перед** "так..." (при сравнении она только посередине).

Comment: Да, всё верно, если посередине, то это сравнение, этот вариант мы не трогаем. А если обособление, то  было бы желательно писать слитно, за исключением значения степени для наречия (хорошо, так же как и).  Но такое понимание встречается редко, его можно не рассматривать для простоты.

Comment: Тогда это уже реально сложно. Таким как раз и занимается Орфографическая комиссия РАН. Вам стоит с ними пообщаться :)

Comment: Это каста неприкасаемых, оттого  такие нелепые решения принимаются. Думаете, у нас мало умных людей, да только никому хода не дают. К тому же не всё они могут окончательно решить, иногда и на попятную идут. Практика на них тоже давит.